# Stripe checkout , getting data after payment

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I have a stripe checkout that redirects the user to the default stripe checkout page on their side and when the payment is complete, it redirects to my website page. The problem is that i need to get some data from the payment and i read the docs and i cant figure out how to recieve that data.

I know that i have to place in the stripe checkout creation code, but i need to have some kind of function to recieve the data that i am passing.

```
 const stripe = await this.stripePromise;
 const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({

     mode: 'subscription',

     lineItems: [{ price: this.priceId, quantity: this.quantity }],

     clientReferenceId: this.userEmail,
     billingAddressCollection: this.userAdress,


     successUrl: `page`,
     cancelUrl: `page`,

   });
```

I am passing the  clientReferenceId and the billingAddressCollection, but how to recieve that on the success page?

Do i need to have some stripe function?

Answer (score 1):

Listen to webhook events such as `payment_intent.succeeded`. Since you are using Checkout, listen to `checkout.session.completed` event.